# Back navigation icon is not shown in ToolBar with SearchView in android

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar, back

I have updated google play services. Before updating I was using ActionBar and everything was fine. But after updating play services I am using ToolBar. Now when I click on search icon on action bar then SearchView is shown but back navigation icon is not visible. but when I click on the place of navigation button it's still functional i.e. it goes back.

Please see attached screen shot.
[image]

then please suggest how can i display this back navigation button.

Comment: add your code in order to help you

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**I have not tried this with search (API 23)**

Add this inside method onCreate(...)

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And then do this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: @Sushil.Thanks for the answer. but i am using ToolBar not actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply but I've come across the issue as well and managed to resolve it in my codebase.

This is happening because the `Toolbar` replaces the navigation icon with its own collapse icon. You need to change the definition in XML to something like below, containing the `collapseIcon` attribute.

```
<Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/my_toolbar_height"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:collapseIcon="@drawable/my_back_icon" />
```

Ideally the implementation would try to use the `navigationIcon` attribute, but that doesn't seem to be the case.